# Date Time Stamp

Tags: vb.net

In  a VS2012 Project I like to set a records datafield (DateTimeStamp) to the current system datetime if the corresponding rowstate is added or modified. To do so I use the code as followes:

```
Private Sub LicenceCheckBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LicenceCheckBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Dim dt As DataTable = EfaDesktopDataSet.Tables("LicenceCheck").GetChanges
    If Not IsNothing(dt) Then
        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            If dr.RowState <> DataRowState.Unchanged And dr.RowState <> DataRowState.Deleted Then
                dr.BeginEdit()
                dr.Item("DateTimeStamp") = Date.Now
                dr.EndEdit()
            End If
        Next
    Else
        Dim dr As DataRow = LicenceCheckBindingSource.Current.row
        If dr.RowState = DataRowState.Unchanged Then
            If isDataChanged(dr, "RuleTitle") Then

            End If
        End If
    End If
    Me.LicenceCheckBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.LicenceCheckTableAdapter.Update(Me.EfaDesktopDataSet.LicenceCheck)
End Sub
```

In the DEBUG steps I recognize that the Date is transfered to the datacolumn but after the update and requering the record the column contains not data.

Any Idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `AcceptChanges` on the `DataTable` after the `loop`.